# Trying to install pip dependencies from a bash script

Tags: python, django, bash, pip, virtualenv

Trying the create setup.sh script file in my current Django project's root directory. Don't have too much experience with bash scripting , so to be honest from file access to configuration the issue can be anything. So what I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
setupBackend() {
  echo "--------------------------- Creating virtual environment ----------------------"
  pip install --upgrade pip
  pip install virtualenv
  virtualenv venv
  source ./venv/Scripts/active

  echo "----------------------- Installing dependencies ------------------------------"
  pip install -r requirements.txt

  echo "----------------------- Running Django server -------------------------"
  python ./kudelasz/manage.py runserver
}
```

And I have this requirements file containing the dependencies

```
asgiref==3.7.2
colorama==0.4.6
distlib==0.3.6
Django==4.2.2
django-tailwind==3.6.0
djangorestframework==3.14.0
djangorestframework-jsonapi==6.0.0
filelock==3.12.2
inflection==0.5.1
mysqlclient==2.2.0
platformdirs==3.7.0
PyMySQL==1.1.0
PyPDF2==3.0.1
pytz==2023.3
sqlparse==0.4.4
termcolor==2.3.0
tzdata==2023.3
virtualenv==20.23.1
```

The probalem I'm facing is, that when the script runs the pip installation, it seems to be trying to install all these stuffs to the global python environment.

At least that's what I'm assuming, because it tell me this:   "Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.7.2 in c:\users\customer\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.7.2)" at each package installation attempt.

I can also see in my venv directory that none of those packages get installed, only the default pip dependencies can be seen. In the end the installation fails due dependency conflicts.
For now I'm just trying to run in on my local windows machine. If I run these things manually, all works fine. Running it in git bash.

Any suggestion is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: `source ./venv/Scripts/active` should be `activate`.

Comment: ohh god, that was really dumb. I was focusing so much on my lack of bash script knowledge, that I completely ignored the possibility of any typo error. Thank you.
@DallogFheir I think you answered in the comment  and not in the answer section. If you add the information as an answer, I will mark it as the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your script: `source ./venv/Scripts/active` should be `source ./venv/Scripts/activate`.

So, the `source` command failed, but the script continued running, and because no virtual environment was active, it installed the dependencies to the global installation of Python.

I assume you didn't notice the message that `source` failed because of the output of `pip install`. In Bash, you can put `set -e` in the beginnning of your script to tell Bash to fail the entire script on the first error, which would be useful here.